# Проигрывание двух звуков по порядку

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

В приложении в MediaPlayer загружаю два звука при нажатии на кнопку, но они проигрываются одновременно. Как сделать так, чтобы второй звук проигрывался только после первого?

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.flats_btn1:
                if (flats == null || !flats.isPlaying()) {
                    flats = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.carrier);
                    flats.start();
                    flats.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer flats) {
                            flats.stop();
                            flats.release();

                            //запускаем следующий так же
                            flats = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.carrier2);
                            flats.start();
                        }
                    });
                }
                break;
```

Лог ошибки:

```
08-15 01:23:33.921: E/AndroidRuntime(912): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-15 01:23:33.921: E/AndroidRuntime(912): java.lang.IllegalStateException
08-15 01:23:33.921: E/AndroidRuntime(912):  at android.media.MediaPlayer.isPlaying(Native Method)
08-15 01:23:33.921: E/AndroidRuntime(912):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
08-15 01:23:33.921: E/AndroidRuntime(912):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
08-15 01:23:33.921: E/AndroidRuntime(912):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
08-15 01:23:33.921: E/AndroidRuntime(912):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-15 01:23:33.921: E/AndroidRuntime(912):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-15 01:23:33.921: E/AndroidRuntime(912):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
08-15 01:23:33.921: E/AndroidRuntime(912):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-15 01:23:33.921: E/AndroidRuntime(912):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-15 01:23:33.921: E/AndroidRuntime(912):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
08-15 01:23:33.921: E/AndroidRuntime(912):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
08-15 01:23:33.921: E/AndroidRuntime(912):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужен слушатель окончания проигрывания.

```
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.carrier);
mp.start();
mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() { 
    @Override 
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) { 
        Log.i("player", "onComplete hit"); 
        mp.stop(); 
        mp.release(); 

        //запускаем следующий так же
        MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.carrier);
        mp.start();
    }
});
```

Comment: Встраивать этот код в условие if (flats == null || !flats.isPlaying()) {? Если сделать так, то при следующем нажатии вылетает ошибка. Код добавил выше в вопрос

Comment: И еще вопрос, можно ли убрать задержку между проигрыванием файлов?

Comment: @turok09, если у вас падает, то надо уточнять на какой строке и с какой ошибкой. А задержку можно убрать, если сначала загрузить файлы в плеер, дождаться окончания их загрузки и только потом запускать

Comment: Можете посмотреть, из-за чего приложение останавливается? Лог ошибки добавил выше

Comment: @turok09, ну, наверное mp.release(); надо убрать...